# Usual topology of the set....

Tags: general-topology

What is the usual topology of the set formed by the union of line segments in $\mathbb{R^2} $, which join the points of $ \mathbb {Q} $ on $ [0,1] $ to the point $ p = (0.1) $.

Comment: The subspace topology as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. That is, by the way, the topology induced by the Euclidean metric restricted to the set.

Comment: Do you mean $p=(0,1)$?

Comment: There are no line segments in $\Bbb R^2$ joining points of $\Bbb Q$ to anything: $\Bbb Q$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. Do you mean the union of line segments joining points of $$\Big(\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]\Big)\times\{0\}$$ to the point $\langle 0,1\rangle$?